# Maven Tomcat deploy plugin with profiles

Tags: maven, tomcat, gwt, maven-tomcat-plugin, gwt-maven-plugin

I am attempting to use profiles in my project pom.xml file to control deployment of my war file to a particular server.  As an example, I have a local profile, and a development server profile.  Here is how I have my profiles set up

```
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>target</name>
                <value>local</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        ...
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://10.16.21.60:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>localTomcat</server>
                        <path>/</path>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>target</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        ...
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://devserverurl:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>devTomcat</server>
                        <path>/</path>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I am calling

```
mvn org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy
```

When I try this, I can see that instead of trying to connect to the IP address provided in my configuration `10.16.21.60`, it is instead attempting to connect to `localhost`.  I have both `devTomcat` and `localTomcat` defined in my local `settings.xml` file with username and password.

If I then add the `-X` option for more info I can see in the debug output for the plugin (**emphasis added**)

```
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05]
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy' with basic configurator -->
    [DEBUG]   (f) charset = ISO-8859-1
    [DEBUG]   (f) contextFile = ....
    [DEBUG]   (f) ignorePackaging = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) mode = war
    [DEBUG]   (f) packaging = war
    [DEBUG]   (f) path = ...
    [DEBUG]   (f) update = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) url = http://localhost:8080/manager/text
    [DEBUG]   (f) version = 2.2
    [DEBUG]   (f) warFile =  ...
    [DEBUG]   (f) settings = org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter@61874b9d
    [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
    [INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/...  
    [DEBUG] No server specified for authentication - using defaults
```

It does not appear that my configuration settings are being adhered to!  The way I thought this would work is that since the `local` profile is activated, it would use that configuration.

I did also try simply having the plugin defined in my `<build>` section, without the profiles, with the same effect.  It always attempts to connect to `http://localhost:8080` with no authentication.

It probably is worth noting that I am also using the `gwt-maven-plugin` for this project, and I don't know if this could be interfering with the tomcat plugin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out I was using the wrong `groupID` for the plugin.  It isn't

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
```

it is

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
```

Works like a champ now!